# Is there a way to create a circular image collage varied in size by variable from within a d3 heatmap, or perhaps some other method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am working on a heatmap display of information. I am using the d3 library to create the groups and subgroups. So far, I was able to create the overarching groups, and I am trying to display a bunch of images in the final layer. However, I am running into an issue where some of the rectangles are being displayed as very slim, and this doesn't look good.

I was wondering about a couple of potential things:

- Is there a way to get them to be more circular, sort of like a collage, so that they are all square/rectangular and could be put around one another to form what is shown in the below image?
- Is there a library that could potentially do all of this that I am simply not aware of?

[image: Sample Image]

I have tried playing around with the d3 layouts, however this is simply not implemented by d3.